# string or binary data would be truncated in table '******', column '******'. Truncated value: '******'

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, errors

One of our applications report on error message 2628:

`string or binary data would be truncated in table '******', column '******'. Truncated value: '******'`

instead of

`String or binary data would be truncated in table 'mytable', column 'mycolumn'. Truncated value: 'myvalue'.`

which I get with SSMS.

What setting do I need to change to get the full message?
I've tried to search for this, but all I get is that I need to set VERBOSE_TRUNCATION_WARNINGS to ON and compatibility_level to 150.
Which I've done ages ago.

The application has this error handler:

```
 try
     {
         ES.isWorking = true;
         Worker worker = new Worker(new DBConnection(Settings.ConnectionString));
         worker.DoWork();
         ES.isWorking = false;
     }
 catch (Exception ex)
     {
         ES.isWorking = false;
         this.eventLog.WriteEntry("In OnTimer exception ! message: " + ex.Message.ToString());
         errorHandler.HandleException(ex, "In OnTimer exception !", ErrorSeverities.Error);
     }
```

The errorHandler looks like this

```
Public Function HandleException(ByVal incommingEx As System.Exception,
                                   ByVal note As String,
                                   ByVal errorSeverity As ErrorSeverities,
                                   Optional ByVal sessionId As String = "",
                                   Optional ByVal applicationSource As String = "",
                                   Optional ByVal ignoreDB As Boolean = False,
                                   Optional ByVal noMail As Boolean = False) As Integer
    Dim stackTraceBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim targetSite As String = ""
    Dim errorTime As DateTime = Now
    Dim messageBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim innerEx As Exception = incommingEx.InnerException
    Dim errorId As Integer = 0
    Dim innerCount As Integer = 1
    Dim loggedToDb As Boolean = False
    Dim appSource As String = Me._applicationSource
    If applicationSource <> "" Then
        appSource = applicationSource
    End If
    '... more code'

    messageBuilder.AppendLine("(" + incommingEx.GetType.Name.ToUpper + ")" + vbCrLf + incommingEx.Message + " - SOURCE: " + incommingEx.Source)
    '...'
    While Not innerEx Is Nothing And innerCount <= 5
        messageBuilder.AppendLine("INNER" + Convert.ToString(innerCount) + " (" + innerEx.GetType.Name.ToUpper + "):" + vbCrLf + **innerEx.Message** + " - SOURCE: " + innerEx.Source)
        If Not innerEx Is Nothing AndAlso Not innerEx.StackTrace Is Nothing Then
            stackTraceBuilder.AppendLine("INNER" + Convert.ToString(innerCount) + ": " + innerEx.StackTrace) 'Me.GetNumberedStack(innerEx))
        End If
        innerEx = innerEx.InnerException
        innerCount += 1
    End While
    '... more code where the error message is inserted in a log table, via a sproc'
End Function
```

We have not seen this behavior before, **but** we have recently updated the .net framework to version 4.7.2, so it could be related.

the error text "string or binary" is comming from the bit that goes

- innerEx.Message +
  and that is a simple built-in Exception data type. So it is VB and/or .net and/or SQL Server that is building the string, **not** us.

The error comes after a call to a stored procedure, where the user has probably entered a varchar(1000) text. The stored procedure adds a bit more, and the table hasn't got room for all 1100 bytes. Hence the error.
The stored procedure does not have a try-catch block.

Comment: it happend again today, but on a different error number, and this time in SSMS, when logged in as sysadmin.

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the ****** value '******' to data type ******.

I accidentially compared an int to a varchar(100).  
Could it be Azure SQL Database version related?

Comment: this was a bug in Azure SQL Database, and Microsoft will try to fix it in one of the next few releases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’ve found that I had added Sensitivity Classification to all my Temporal Tables, (and only to some of my non-Temporal Tables).

As in

```
add SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION to dbo.Mytable.name with (LABEL = 'General', INFORMATION_TYPE = 'Public')
```

when I drop the Sensitivity Classification, the old error message is back.

I have an example that demonstrates the error:

```
drop table if exists dbo.mytable
go
create table dbo.Mytable (i int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered, name varchar(10) not null)
go
insert into dbo.Mytable ( name ) values ( 'abc' )
go
select * from dbo.Mytable where name = 1  -- programming error; data type mis-match
```

returns

```
(1 row affected)
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'abc' to data type int.
```

This is the **correct** error message.
Now run this:

```
add SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION to dbo.Mytable.name with (LABEL = 'General', INFORMATION_TYPE = 'Public')
```

and when you run this

```
select * from dbo.Mytable where name = 1 -- programming error; data type mis-match
```

You will see this

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 169
Conversion failed when converting the ****** value '******' to data type ******.
```

This is the **in-correct** error message.
I've tried this code on Azure SQL Database where I get the in-correct message, and on SQL Server 2019 CU6, where I only get the correct message.
I have reported this to Microsoft, and they have acknowledged that this is a bug, and that it will be fixed in a few months.

I have created two scripts to 1) document existing classifications, and 2) drop all those classifications.

The scripts can be found here:
[document and drop classifications](https://github.com/HenrikStaunPoulsen/DocumentAndDropSensitivityClassification)

Answer (score 13):

It looks like this table was defined with [dynamic data masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15), and the user that the application uses to access the database doesn't have permission to view masked data (which is good!).

This is why the behavior differs between the application and SSMS: I expect you're using a higher-privileged user when running the query from SSMS

Here's a demo:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Filler varchar(100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(1,"XXXXXXX",0)') NULL
);
GO

CREATE USER TestUser WITHOUT LOGIN;  
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Test TO TestUser;  
GRANT INSERT ON dbo.Test TO TestUser;
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestUser';
INSERT dbo.Test 
    (Filler)
VALUES
    (REPLICATE(N'A', 101)); 
REVERT;
```

The result of which is:

```
Msg 2628, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
String or binary data would be truncated in table '******', column '******'. Truncated value: '******'.
```

To get the full message in the application, you'll need to grant the user the `UNMASK` permission:

```
GRANT UNMASK TO TestUser;
```

Running the `INSERT` code again results in the full error text:

```
Msg 2628, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
String or binary data would be truncated in table 'tempdb.dbo.Test', column 'Filler'. Truncated value: 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'.
```

---

When using Azure SQL Database, Dynamic Data Masking can also be configured in the Azure Portal user interface.  You may want to check there (although as far as I can tell, masks set up this way still update the `sys.columns` metadata):

[image: Screenshot of dynamic data masking rule set up in the Azure Portal]

I would also check if there are other databases that are part of the same logical SQL Server instance in Azure - maybe there are some kind of strange, cross-database queries going on.

Comment: There are no masked columns in the database at all. But your answer may still be valid, because the user only have rights to execute stored procedures (no table access at all).

Answer (score 7):

I think it is related to a new and underreported bug in Azure SQL Database (only), where Temporal Tables are treated different from normal tables, when the errors 245 and 2628 occur.

Answer (score 6):

The masking in the error message can occur also in scenarios unrelated to Dynamic Data Masking (or temporal tables). See the following example:

```
CREATE DATABASE ErrorMessageTest
GO
USE ErrorMessageTest
GO
CREATE USER SimpleUser WITHOUT LOGIN
GO
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER SimpleUser
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Numbers(@MaxNumber int)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
 WITH Nbrs_4( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 0 ),
          Nbrs_3( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_4 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_4 n2 ),
          Nbrs_2( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_3 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_3 n2 ),
          Nbrs_1( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_2 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_2 n2 ),
          Nbrs_0( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_1 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_1 n2 ),
          Nbrs  ( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_0 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_0 n2 )
        SELECT n
          FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n)
                   FROM Nbrs ) D ( n )
         WHERE n <= @MaxNumber ;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@Param nvarchar(MAX),@Separator NCHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN 
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Param, N, CHARINDEX(@Separator, @Param + @Separator, n) - n) AS VALUE, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) AS Position
FROM dbo.Numbers(LEN(@Param)) n
WHERE SUBSTRING(@Separator + @Param, n, 1) = @Separator

GO
EXECUTE AS USER='SimpleUser'

DECLARE @ApplyToMonth NVARCHAR(101) = '1,2,3,4,5,6, test error message,8'

SELECT t.VALUE AS OriginalValue, TRY_CAST(REPLACE(t.VALUE, ' ', '') AS INT) AS IntValue
    FROM dbo.Split(@ApplyToMonth, ',') t
SELECT    x.OriginalValue, x.IntValue,
        CASE WHEN x.IntValue IS NULL THEN CAST(x.OriginalValue AS INT) ELSE 0 END AS RaisErrorColumn
FROM (
    SELECT t.VALUE AS OriginalValue, TRY_CAST(REPLACE(t.VALUE, ' ', '') AS INT) AS IntValue
    FROM dbo.Split(@ApplyToMonth, ',') t
) x

GO
REVERT
GO
USE master
GO
DROP DATABASE ErrorMessageTest
```

In SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server 2017, this produces the following error message:

```
Conversion failed when converting the ****** value '******' to data type ******.
```

Surprisingly, the solution in this case is the same as in the other cases: `GRANT UNMASK TO SimpleUser`

I am inclined to say that this is a bug, because in SQL Server 2019 CU5, I get the full error message (without granting UNMASK):

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ' test error message' to data type int.
```

Answer (score 5):

The behavior you are seeing (i.e. meta-data being replaced by `***` in error messages for non-`sysadmin` / non-`dbo` accounts) appears to be the effect of trace flag 3625: [Metadata Visibility Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/metadata-visibility-configuration). I don't have an Azure account to test with, but the documentation does indicate that this feature is available in Azure SQL Database.

A far less likely possibility (in fact, it shouldn't even be possible at this point) is that someone configured the short-lived ([thankfully!](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2019/08/05/feature-restrictions-in-sql-server-2019-are-worse-than-useless-a-false-sense-of-security-and-wasted-opportunity/)) "feature restrictions" option for `ERRORMESSAGE`, which was effectively the same thing as trace flag 3625. There were a few months, I believe, when the "Feature Restrictions" feature was being phased-out that it was possible for it to have been configured previously but no longer fully accessible. However, that feature should have been 100% removed (from Azure SQL Database) by March 4th, 2020 at the latest.